# feathers-authentication-hooks: restrictToRoles for a user with more then one role

Tags: javascript, feathersjs, feathers-authentication

I have implemented `feathers-authentication-hooks` in my project and it is working verifying against a custom user column containing a role. Now I want to have it working with more then one role per user. I've trying several formats in the database column, but all have failed:

Data formats (exact format per line):

`role1, role2
role1; role2
[role1,role2]
{"column_name": ["role1","role2"]}`

does someone know what I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most hooks in that package can be implemented manually often with the same amount of code and less time than it takes to read the documentation. In this case for your example with a custom hook like this:

```
const { Unauthorized } = require('feathers-errors');

return function() {
  return function(context) {
    if(context.params.user.roles.indexOf('admin') === -1) {
      throw new Unauthorized('You are not allowed to access this');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Daff. This works but I need to fine tune it for it doesn't check a complete role name if the list would be comma seperated for example. The index of will also return if a different role has this text in it. I found that the feathers-authention-hooks restrict-to-roles also does that (its the same sort of code snippit). I think doing it like `context.params.user.roles.split(',').indexOf('admin')` will be better

Comment: Sure, my point was that it is much easier to adjust to whatever you need instead of digging through docs and someone else's code.